# Referencing textview in Asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am using an asynctask to do some xml stuff and I want to update the textview when finished but I am having the following issue whereby I cannot reference the textview using findViewById.

```
public class HTTPRequestTask extends AsyncTask<String , Void, String > {

  @Override
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

    q = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.xmlData); //cannot resolve findViewbyId
```

I would then like to update the textview in the post execute method.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
   super.onPostExecute(s);{
        q.setText(s);
    }
}
```

What is the most straight forward way to be able to set the text in the postExecute method??

Comment: Your code will cause **memory leak** in that case use `WeakReference` on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass either `Activity` variable or `TextView` variable into `HTTPRequestTask`

I mean, create constructor,

```
    public class HTTPRequestTask extends AsyncTask<String , Void, String > {

    private Activity act;
private TextView q;
        public HTTPRequestTask (Activity act) {
        this.act = act;
 q = (TextView)act.findViewById(R.id.xmlData);
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        //some code with your q
```

To start task use this:

`new HTTPRequestTask(this).execute();`

Comment: Use `WeakReference` that is a potential memory leak.

Comment: @Enzokie , I've never faces this problem using such implementation.

Comment: How does one pass those particular variables to the class when it can only take 3 arguments?

Comment: That works fine now but i'm still unsure what it is doing. Why create the public method within the class and, what does "this" do?

Comment: @MXG123 , we creates a constructor where we pass the object as a parameter.

Comment: @MXG123 , the object is activity which has got `findViewById` method

Comment: @MXG123 so, we saves the acvity that stores our textview. and calls its method later

Comment: @MXG123 ,`this` is current object. We you it here to pass itself into another object - asynctask

Answer (score 0):

You should refer to the `Activity class` where the class `HTTPRequestTask` is embedded.

E.g: `MyActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.xmlData);`

Comment: It seems, this class in the other java file.

Comment: How do you confirm that?

Comment: IDE helps to resolve this issue if this class is a subclass.

Comment: I am new to java so I dont really know what you mean. I put q = MyActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.xmlData); below the class head but gives a lot of errors. How should it be implemented?

Comment: The class is in another java file. Does it behave differently if in a seperate file?